# Mayavi mlab glitch - rendering will not update on rotation

Tags: mlab, mayavi

When I render a 3D graph on an installation of Mayavi on a different device, I noticed it had a weird thin outline and a black background. Then when I rotate the graph it exhibits a glitch that doesn't erase the image of its previous position. I didn't have this problem when I installed Mayavi on my own device. Does anyone know what the problem might be?
[image: maya]

Comment: Can it be related to your graphics drivers?

Comment: @Patol75 Thank you. that was it. I just needed to update the graphics driver and that fixed the problem.

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out. :)